# Al borrar con AJAX que desaparezca un div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

quiero que se borre por completo un dip en el acto sin necesidad de actualizar. Pero no me desaparece, la función que hace `act-todas.php` si me funciona correcto.

Lo estoy haciendo del siguiente modo.

```
<div class="vistasTodas">Aquí el contenido</div>
```

**Aquí el AJAX**

```
$(function()
  {
    $(".borrar_Todas").click(function()
    {
      if(confirm("¿Seguro que quieres marcarlas como leidas?"))
        {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/act-todas.php",
          success: function(){}
          });
          $(this).parents(".vistasTodas").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
          .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
          toastr["warning"]("Notificaciónes vistas", "Mensaje")
        }
       return false;
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la funcion que le pasas a "success" de tu ajax puedes meter el codigo que necesites ejecutar, incluso validar parametros de retorno de tu metodo "act-todas.php".
Algo asi:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/act-todas.php",
      success: function(result){
                   //result <= si regresas algo en tu llamada, aqui se almacena
                   //aqui dentro va el codigo que quieres se ejecute cuando 
                   //tu llamada termine. Para ocultar tu div un ejemplo seria:
                   $('.vistasTodas').hide();
               }
});
```

Ojo si quieres manejar los errores que puediesen existir al realizar tu llamada tienes que  setearle una funcion a "error" y hacer algo parecido como con la de "success".

La documentacion a fondo aqui:
[jQuery.ajax() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Hola y bienvenido! gracias por tu solución. Me sirvió a la perfección!